# paypal express checkout notify url without api

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a situation I am unable to fine the answer. I am using Paypal Express checkout method by simple form method not api . when user/buyer reaches the paypal payment page and after successful payment it give user/buyer two button option ( your paypal account ) - ( return to site) If user returns to site good enough get all the transaction details but incase he does not there is no way to capture the transaction result. Is there a return url that can be specified in the html express checkout method also does it require the seller to enable Ipin in his account or is it enable by default .

My issue is its a thirdparty application where seller adds his paypal account to accept payment but one successful payment it needs to return the website . issue cant ask seller to enable any specific things to his paypal account as if he does or does not there is no way for me to verify while he sets up the account to my service or platform .

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using Instant Payment Notification (IPN) to handle that instead of Payment Data Transfer (PDT).  They're essentially the same thing except that PDT only works on the return URL (which isn't guaranteed to get hit as you're finding out) and IPN will be triggered in the background regardless of whether or not the buyer makes it back to your return URL.

You can include the "notify_url" parameter in your HTML form code to pass the URL you'd like the IPN's to get sent to.  This will override any setting the merchant might have setup in their own PayPal account.